# "Helicopter lift" card

Tags: forbidden-island

Just a small clarification regarding the use of the aformentioned card. I know that you can use it during others players' round. What confuses me is its use.

Let's say I'm the one holding this card. Can I use it to move another player's pawn and not mine, even if he's not on the same tile as my pawn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/609867/helicopter-lift-card) on BoardGameGeek asks the same question.  According to [this post](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25430910#25430910), the game developer provided this ruling:

> The user of the card does not need to be on the same tile as the pawns being moved.